# How to use the accelerometer to detect virbration above 1Gs?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I'm doing android application which is something like a car blackbox which records the traveling process of the car.

But now I'm face with the problem of how am i going to integrate an accelerometer which is capable of detecting slight movement (Probably > 1Gs) when an accident occur it could trigger the video recording to stop and saving it to the Archive file, thus not losing the file as a result to the accident.. Anyone knows how to do the above mention task to monitor any forms of vibration?

I'm new to android/java could someone help guide me along? Thanks in advance...

This is part of the section of the video recording but now how am i going to incorporate accelerometer for "Auto-Archiving" purposes?

Comment: The first try block is missing a `{` and a `catch` block!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` callback of the interface `SensorEventListener`

Get the details of the `SensorEvent` class here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

There's an example on the IBM's developerWorks page: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-sensor/index.html

---

**From the android reference pages:**

> public final float[]
>
> values Since: API
>   Level 3
>
> The length and contents of the values
>   array depends on which sensor type is
>   being monitored (see also SensorEvent
>   for a definition of the coordinate
>   system used).
>   Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER: All values
>   are in SI units (m/s^2)
>
> `values[0]`: Acceleration minus Gx on the x-axis
>
> `values[1]`: Acceleration minus Gy on the y-axis
>
> `values[2]`: Acceleration minus Gz on the z-axis
>
> A sensor of this type measures the
>   acceleration applied to the device
>   (Ad). Conceptually, it does so by
>   measuring forces applied to the sensor
>   itself (Fs) using the relation: Ad = -
>   ∑Fs / mass
>
> In particular, the force of gravity is
>   always influencing the measured
>   acceleration: Ad = -g - ∑F / mass
>
> For this reason, when the device is
>   sitting on a table (and obviously not
>   accelerating), the accelerometer reads
>   a magnitude of g = 9.81 m/s^2
>
> Similarly, when the device is in
>   free-fall and therefore dangerously
>   accelerating towards to ground at 9.81
>   m/s^2, its accelerometer reads a
>   magnitude of 0 m/s^2.
>
> It should be apparent that in order to
>   measure the real acceleration of the
>   device, the contribution of the force
>   of gravity must be eliminated. This
>   can be achieved by applying a
>   high-pass filter. Conversely, a
>   low-pass filter can be used to isolate
>   the force of gravity.

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
 {
      // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
      // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
      // and dT, the event delivery rate

      final float alpha = 0.8;

      gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
      gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
      gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

      linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
      linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
      linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. But i'm not really that good in physics unfortunately... But how am i going to implement your above codes into my current activity class to sense any sort of collision greater than 1G of force?

Comment: @Vivian did you read the links above? There you have examples on how to implement the listener. Use then the code posted for `onSensorChanged(...)` and do whatever you want with the array `linear_acceleration`. In your case, I would think you need acceleration values much larger than 1G to detect a collision. I don't know the values, though and you'll have to research what will be the best threshold. One last tip: consider the **absolute value** of the acceleration.

Comment: Sorry if i could not understand you well or the documentation you offered, i'm really an amateur when it comes to programming of android for only a month or so and this assignment is only given to me for another two weeks to complete by my lecturer... :( Because i don't quite understand exactly how am i going to code onSensorChanged(...) with the values of linear_acceleration to trigger a stop of the recording and archive it into a directory? I know i might be asking too much of you being this is not your assignment.. But could you give me more help?

Comment: @Vivian, add an if block inside the `onSensorChanged` method, and call a `startRecording()` function in the case your acceleration is higher than your threshold. You should be able to discuss implementation details with your lecturer. Also, I see that you have three answered questions. Please, consider to mark them as accepted. Remember that this is a site to ask specific questions, not fully functional blocks of code.

Comment: can tell me which of these two answer is a better answer? -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321476/speedometer-using-accelerometer-no-output and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003461/android-accelerometer-to-measure-speed