# android accelerometer to measure speed

Tags: android, accelerometer

im trying to make an speedometer using the accelerometer but for some reason the code is crashing can someone please tell me what is wrong and how to fix it
thank you

this is the red part in logcat:

```
05-14 13:03:55.826: INFO/ActivityManager(91): Start proc com.hanud.speedo for activity com.hanud.speedo/.speedometer: pid=2052 uid=10127 gids={}
05-14 13:03:56.806: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2052): Shutting down VM
05-14 13:03:56.806: WARN/dalvikvm(2052): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207f0)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.hanud.speedo/com.hanud.speedo.speedometer}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hanud.speedo.speedometer in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.hanud.speedo-2.apk]
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hanud.speedo.speedometer in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.hanud.speedo-2.apk]
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-14 13:03:56.986: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2052):     ... 11 more
05-14 13:03:57.017: WARN/ActivityManager(91):   Force finishing activity com.hanud.speedo/.speedometer
05-14 13:03:57.526: WARN/ActivityManager(91): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4382d820 com.hanud.speedo/.speedometer}
05-14 13:04:05.666: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1890): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4544 objects / 322792 bytes in 288ms
05-14 13:04:07.796: WARN/ActivityManager(91): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4382d820 com.hanud.speedo/.speedometer}
05-14 13:04:12.016: INFO/ActivityManager(91): Start proc com.android.email for service com.android.email/.service.MailService: pid=2058 uid=10004 gids={3003, 1015}
```

and this is the code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Speedometer extends Activity {

  Handler handler = new Handler();

  SensorManager sensorManager;
    TextView myTextView;

    float appliedAcceleration = 0;
    float currentAcceleration = 0;
    float velocity = 0;
    Date lastUpdate;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
      lastUpdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

      sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
      Sensor accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener,
                                       accelerometer,
                                       SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);


      Timer updateTimer = new Timer("velocityUpdate");
      updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
          updateGUI();
        }
      }, 0, 1000);
    }

    private void updateGUI() {
      // Convert from meters per second to miles per hour.
      final double mph = (Math.round(100*velocity / 1.6 * 3.6))/100;

      // Update the GUI
      handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mph) + "mph");
      }
    });
    }

  private void updateVelocity() {
      // Calculate how long this acceleration has been applied.
      Date timeNow = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
      long timeDelta = timeNow.getTime()-lastUpdate.getTime();
      lastUpdate.setTime(timeNow.getTime());

      // Calculate the change in velocity at the 
      // current acceleration since the last update. 
      float deltaVelocity = appliedAcceleration * (timeDelta/1000);
      appliedAcceleration = currentAcceleration;

      // Add the velocity change to the current velocity.
      velocity += deltaVelocity;
    }

  //private final SensorListener sensorListener = new SensorListener() {
  private final SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    double calibration = Double.NaN;



      public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        double x = event.values[0];
        double y = event.values[1];
        double z = event.values[2];

      double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2)); 

      if (calibration == Double.NaN)
        calibration = a;
      else {
        updateVelocity();
        currentAcceleration = (float)a;
      }
    }
      public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) { }
  };
}
```

Comment: This sounds more of a AndroidManifest.xml problem. In your LogCat output it complains `ClassNotFoundException: com.hanud.speedo.speedometer` while your class is named `Speedometer`.

Comment: Even if you fix your code, it's not going to work very well.  Integrating acceleration to determine velocity is extremely prone to accumulating error.

Comment: How did the speed results pan out with the acceleration? Did it work well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You defined (probably in the android manifest) `com.hanud.speedo.speedometer`, while your activity's name is `Speedometer` (with capital `S`).

Just to make it clear - change the name of the activity in the Manifest file to **Speedometer**.

Comment: does the above code requires any permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @Lucifer it doesn't need any permission as accelerometer is part of almost all android devices and all devices support this sensor powered by OS